# select a field from the minus query

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select a, b, c from tab1
minus
select d, e, f from tab2
```

Above is how my query looks like. How to I reformat my query to display a, b, c and f?

I tried the below but I keep getting invalid identifier.

```
select t.a, t.b, t.c, t.f from
(select a, b, c from tab1
minus
select d, e, f from tab2)t
```

thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to show some sample data and desired results.  This is often better than showing query code that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, recall that operator `minus` takes the results of the first query (i.e. rows with columns `a, b, c` from `tab1`) and removes all rows such that there is a corresponding row in `tab2`, such that the combination of its columns `d, e, f` matches a combination of `a, b, c` from `tab1`.

Now it should be clear that what you are trying to do does not make sense: all rows from the second select, i.e.

```
select d, e, f from tab2
```

are *excluded* from the rows returned by the first select. In other words, there would not be a single row in the result with a value that came from column `f` (or for that matter, from any of the columns of `tab2`).

Answer (score 0):

The following query will display rows that are present in both `tabl1` and `tab2` tables, but with different values for `tab1.c` and `tab2.f`. If you want to display rows that are present in `tab1`, but even the a and b values are not present in `tab2`, then the WHERE clause can be modified accordingly.

```
select tab1.a, tab1.b, tab1.c, tab2.f
from tab1 FULL OUTER JOIN tab2
ON tab1.a = tab2.d AND tab1.b = tab2.e
WHERE
-- (tab1.a IS NOT NULL AND tab1.b IS NOT NULL) AND 
-- (tab1.c IS NULL OR tab2.f IS NULL) OR
(NVL(tab1.c, 0) <> NVL(tab2.f, 0));
```

Here is a <kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/56dc24/3)</kbd>.